# Problems when migrating a repository from SVN to GITLAB

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, git-svn

I have a very large repository in SVN with the following structure:

```
http://mycompany.com/svn/something/
│   
│  
│
└───branches
│   │   
│   └───MyProject_FIX
│   │   │   
│   │   └(SOURCE CODE)   
│   │   
│   └───MyProject_Branch2
│   │   │   
│   │   └(SOURCE CODE) 
│   │
│   │
│   │
│   └───OtherProject_FIX
│       │   
│       └(SOURCE CODE)   
│
│
│
└───tags
│   │   
│   └───MyProject
│   │   │   
│   │   └1.0.0
|   |   |  └(SOURCE CODE)
│   │   │
|   │   └1.0.1
|   │   |  └(SOURCE CODE)
│   │   │
|   │   └1.0.3    
|   │   |  └(SOURCE CODE)
│   │   │
|   │   (...)
│   │   │
│   │   └latest
│   │
│   └───OtherProject   
│
└───trunk
    |
    └───MyProject
    |    |
    |    └─(SOURCE CODE)
    |
    └───OtherProject
         |
         └─(SOURCE CODE)
```

I have tried almost everything:

- git svn clone
- This script: https://github.com/JohnAlbin/git-svn-migrate
- The import option in github
- This tutorial from bitbucket: https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview
- This tool: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

And the only think that I have achieved is to import the same structure of the SVN repository with the commits.

What I would like to do is to convert the tag folder intro real git tags, the branch folder intro real branches and import only MyProject (Ignoring the OtherProject)

Finally I have to say that the repository is quite large (I don't know if this detail is important)

Is there any straightforward way to convert this repository?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should be doable with plain old git-svn provided that you set up branches correctly. You can set them up one by one (if you are not talking about dozens of tags) using `fetch` lines (one for each branch) inside the .git/config file in the section for the svn repo. Tags? I don't have much experience there so won't give you any advice there (though I assume it should be possible to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use the trunk/branches/tags command line options for git svn:

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk/MyProject --branches=/branches/MyProject_Branch2 --branches=/branches/MyProject_FIX --tags=/tags/MyProject http://mycompany.com/svn/something/ <dest repo>
```

This should pull out just MyProject.

Remember to include your authors file and put in `--prefix==` to ensure that the atlassian clean up script that converts svn tags to real tags works properly.